# invalid_grant error trying to refresh access token for googleapis

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

We use the googleapis for our web app and store and manage the access token and refresh token to our database.
When we refresh the access token of users using refresh token, rarely we had the **GaxiosError: invalid_grant**.

Now, we use the google api nodejs client[ https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client ].
We store the access token and the refresh token to our database for each user and  they are updated by bellow logic per 6 hours.

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';

// create oauth2client for google apis
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_secret, client_id, redirect_uri);

// set current access token and refresh token (==current_tokens)
oAuth2Client.setCredentials(current_tokens);

// refresh access token and refresh token
// new_token contains access_token and refresh_token
const new_token = await oAuth2Client.refreshAccessToken();

// store the new access token and new refresh token to database
...
```

Does anyone know what may be causing **GaxiosError: invalid_grant**?
I'm getting the feeling that it may be due to the refresh token being updated every 6 hours.

**Additional Info**

the setting of generating auth url

```
const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: GOOGLE_APIS_SCOPE, // GOOGLE_APIS_SCOPE contains scopes
        prompt: 'consent',
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons why a refresh token will expire If we check the documentation for [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) You will find a list of them here.

- The user has revoked your app's access.
- The refresh token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.
- The user belongs to a Google Cloud Platform organization that has session control - policies in effect.
- A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

Currently the most common reason would be that your application is not set to production if its still in testing then your refresh token will expire in a week.

You mention that its stored in the database every six hours.  I would double check if you are refreshing the access token every six hours and that it does return a new refresh token each time that you are in fact updating the database with the most current refresh token otherwise you may be reaching the "maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens"

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Application is already on production.

We refresh access token and store it to database every 6 hours using oAuth2Client.refreshAccessToken function.

Also I confirmed that program uses latest access and refresh token every refreshing.

Comment: Basically, do we keep using the same refresh token in googleapis for an user?
In other words, do we need to update the refresh token?

Comment: In my exprence it depends on the Client library weither or not you get a new refresh token with every request or if it just continues to use the same one.  I know the PHP client library has a habit of giving you the same one, while the .net client library you tend to get a new one each time.   Which means I would update the refresh token just in case its not the same one as the one you currently have stored.